# Install Android SDK on Eclipse Java EE

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I have installed Android SDK on my Eclipse JavaEE.

[image]

The problem is when I click on windows, it does not have Android SDK and ADV Manager in the menu bar.

Can you help me what did I miss?

I have done all the steps described in [Android SDK installation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: Android has provided the new ADT which has all the required tools.Its on their main page and isnt it easy if you can get everything in the same download?

Comment: Yes that is possible. What I missed is in @Androider answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have figured it out on your eclipse menu bar go to

1) window

2) customize perspective

3) command group availability tab
   on the check box android SDK and AVD manager check it

4) click on ok

That should work.

Comment: Glad I could help. You could accept it as answer if it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't show  on clicking windows.

Follow the following steps

1)Install ADT plugin from developer.android.com use [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

2)Go to Help->Install new software-> and give either url or local adt file as mentioned in link

3)Once installed you will see avd manager and sdk manager icons at the top of eclipse

4)Update SDK manager by clicking the SDK manager icon.  It will show anrdroid versions to

install

Answer (score 0):

Go to
1) Menu Bar Window
2) Perspective
3) Open perspective
4) click on Java